# Где лучше разместить файлы?

Tags: javascript, html, django, reactjs

Я новичок в программировании. Возник вопрос, как правильно разместить файлы. Для бекэнда я использую `Django`, для фронтенда `React`. Было решено в зависимости от типа функции размещать ее или там, или там. Например логику чата (ChatLogic.js) я думал разместить в `React`, однако у меня в `templates Django` находятся html-страницы, и к одной из них я должен подключить `ChatLogic.js`. Для этого мне придется делать компиляцию и потом переносить из `build` в джанго `static`. Отсюда вопрос, а зачем мне тогда размещать в React, да и вообще зачем мне сам React, если я буду все равно переносить файлы в static Джанго? С компиляцией у меня проблемы, поэтому я хотел бы как-то без нее обойтись. Так же, если делать компиляцию, я так понял, что она не автоматическая, мне придется после каждого изменения кода выполнять эту рутину? Это же бред. Просьба разъяснить вышеперчисленные моменты. Заранее спасибо.